# CLIPS: how to add conditions to do-for-all-facts construct?

Tags: clips, expert-system

I have a do-for-all-facts construct with logical conditions to filter only some facts:

```
(do-for-all-facts ((?hotel albergo)) 
        (eq ?hotel:localita ?current-city)
        (>= ?hotel:disponibilita (/ ?number-of-people 2))
        (<= (* ?hotel:prezzo ?current-days) ?budget-for-locality)
            (printout t (>= ?hotel:disponibilita (/ ?number-of-people 2)) crlf)
            (if (> ?hotel:disponibilita ?max)
                then
                    (bind ?most-available-hotel ?hotel)
                    (bind ?max ?hotel:disponibilita)
            )
)
```

It seems that doesn't filter properly, because the

```
(printout t (>= ?hotel:disponibilita (/ ?number-of-people 2)) crlf)
```

line prints FALSE. How can I value in logical AND all the conditions in `do-for-all-facts` construct?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using only one condition in the fact-set-query.